# Navbar not working in angular 2

Tags: html, angular

I am trying to make a navigation bar having images which upon clicking navigate to some component. Following is the code.

```
<nav class="sidenav col-md-1">
        <ul class="menu" routerLinkActive="active">
            <li class="menu-item">
                <img src="../../assets/images/Mask Group 7.svg" alt="Logo" style="height: 100%">
            </li>
             <li class="menu-item">
                <a routerLink="dashboard" routerLinkActive="active">
                 <img src="../../assets/images/home.svg" alt="Home" style="height: 100%">
                 </a>
            </li>
             <li class="menu-item">
               <a routerLink="dashboard" routerLinkActive="active">
                 <img src="../../assets/images/accept-file-or-checklist.svg" alt="Home" style="height: 100%">
                 </a>
            </li>
             <li class="menu-item">
                <a routerLink="dashboard" routerLinkActive="active">
                 <img src="../../assets/images/folded-text-document.svg" alt="Home" style="height: 100%"> 
                 </a>
            </li>
             <li class="menu-item">
                <a routerLink="dashboard" routerLinkActive="active">
                 <img src="../../assets/images/wukla_logo.svg" alt="Home" style="height: 100%">
                 </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
  </nav>
```

Problem is that when I use `<a>` tag within `<li>` tag image is not displaying. And it not clickable as well. Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: create a plunker for better understanding your problem

Comment: try by changing your routerLink  as routerLink = '/dashboard'

Comment: still no luck @Sami

Comment: any progress here?

Comment: i was using wrong syntax. I followed Angular official documentation and problem was resolved. what I needed to add was  only this `routerLink ="/connect"`

Answer (score 1):

put the routerLink="" in the 
(li) tag and not in (a) tag.
it will work fine.

Comment: sorry! I didn't understand! can you please explain a bit!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways given below :

1. Use href like href="page url" like "/live/work/findwork" on anchor tag 
   and define the image under the anchor tag
2. Or you can use ui-sref instead of href like ui-sref="work.upcomingsessions" is the routing url

It will work in both ways.

Answer (score 0):

This might work with anchor tag:

[routerLink] = " ['/dashboard'] "  [routerLinkActive] = " ['active'] "

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of the syntax of `routerLink` and `routerLinkActive`. Try this:

```
<nav class="sidenav col-md-1">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="menu-item" routerLinkActive="active">
                <a [routerLink]="['/dashboard']"><img src="../../assets/images/Mask Group 7.svg" alt="Logo" style="height: 100%"></a>
            </li>
            ...
        </ul>
</nav>
```

Where `active` is a css class.

Answer (score 0):

when it is navigating to **another Component** , use the correct **path entry** in **app.module.ts** where the **Routes** are Defined,
Thanks